# How Can do some operation once UI rendered completely in Angular8

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8, angular9

I want to perform some operation only after UI completely rendered.

Since child component is coming as undefined

child-component is from library (component from another application added as dependency). So I can't modify/enhance child-component

**my.html**

```
<div>
  <h4>Parent</h4>
  <child-component  #childComponent></child-component>
</div>
```

**my.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('childComponent', {read: ChildComponent, static: false}) private child: ChildComponent;

private myFunction(): void {
  console.log('child', this.child); // This prints undefined. 
  if(this.child) {
   // DO some operations
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do it in different ways, for example: 1) set @Output in child and in its `ngAfterViewInit` trigger the function in parent, 2) set a service with an observable, update the value on child's `ngAfterViewInit`, subscribe to it in parent and inside sub call your function. There are other ways, depending on what you prefer and if this is just a minimal display of issue or you actually have more nested children or more total children at the same level etc.

Comment: Misha, Than you for your response. Actually child-component is from a dependency. So I dnt have access to modify its implementation

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good enough, you just need to trigger `myFunction()` when the child is loaded, and that can be checked from Angular's `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook:

```js
@ViewChild('childComponent', { static: false }) child: ChildComponent;
    
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myFunction();
}
    
myFunction(): void {
    console.log('child', this.child); // This prints undefined.
    if (this.child) {
        // DO some operations
    }
}
```

Check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-to-child-communication-avxqor I've added var into child component just to show that it's accessible this way, and added a console.log on child's OnInit to show that the child is initiated before parent's `ngAfterViewInit` hook.